# c# EF generating wrong table names on SQL Compact

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

Using latest EF and EF SQL Compact (6.1.1) with SQL (4.0)....

Noticed via Linqpad that the table names generated through my initializer (DropCreateDatabaseAlways) are different than what I have specified in the **Table** attribute.  When developing I am creating an embedded database for test purposes but other environment the database will be legacy which means the table names must match then.

If I have **[Table("p_Brand_Visited")]** on an entity the generated table name is **P_Brand_Visiteds**.  The first letter is capitalized and the name is made plural.  Not sure why the **Table** attribute is not respected.  Maybe a SqlCe issue?

Tried via the **OnModelCreating** event to remove pluralizing:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
   modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
 }
```

No effect.  Tried to set the table name:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
   modelBuilder.Entity<BrandVisited>().ToTable("p_Brand_Visited");
 }
```

No effect.  Any other suggestions?  Ways to debug?

Answer (score 0):

This was a problem with Linqpad and the plural options.  Once these were disabled everything worked fine.